# Parse text with dynamic variables in java

Tags: java, parsing, variables, text, dynamic-variables

I need to parse text, and put varibales into it. Something like that:

```
lorem ${var} dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit
```

end put `String var = "ipsum"` insted of `${var}`

What the easyest way to do that? I'm going to use regexp and matcher. But may be spring (or something else) already has this functionality?

Comment: If you're using Spring, you could probably make use of this class: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/PropertyPlaceholderHelper.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Java standard class [MessageFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html) is relatively close to what you want, but it doesn't handle arbitrary placeholder names. If that is needed, your best bet really are regular expressions. If you don't think they are fast, I advise you to measure before turning your back on them. Here's an outline:

```
final Map<String, String> vars = new HashMap<String, String>();
vars.put("var", "ipsum");
final String s = "lorem ${var} dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit";
final Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\$\\{(.*?)\\}").matcher(s);
final StringBuffer b = new StringBuffer(s.length());
while (m.find()) m.appendReplacement(b, vars.get(m.group(1)));
m.appendTail(b);
System.out.println(b);
```

Comment: This approach is actually quite fast.

Comment: @Soronthar One blemish is that `Matcher` forces the use of `StringBuffer` which is synchronized.

Answer (score 0):

`String` has a built-in wrapper for a regex expression: `String replaceAll(String regex, String replacement)`

try:

```
 String result = "lorem ${var} dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit".replaceAll("\\$\\{var\\}", "ipsum");
```

Comment: Thank you. But what about speed, becouse text can be rather big.

Comment: @user1406196 Well, do you want the easiest way to do this, or one that performs well?

Comment: I need a balance. You know, when you use famous libs, like apache commons, you can be sure in such things.

Comment: commons has a replace method in `StringUtils`. It iterates over the input, and searches using `String` methods like `indexOf` and `substring`.